# C++ port of AtomicLong.lazySet

Tags: java, c++, atomic

I'm trying to port some Java code to Windows C++ and am confused about how to implement `AtomicLong.lazySet()`. The only information I can find talks about what it does but not how to implement it, and the available source code ends up in a private native library owned by Sun (`sun.misc.Unsafe.class`).

I currently just set a member variable to the passed parameter but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
class AtomicLong
{
public:
    inline void LazySet(__int64 aValue)
    {
        // TODO: Is this correct?
        iValue = aValue;
    }

    inline void Set(__int64 aValue)
    {
        ::InterlockedExchange64(&iValue, aValue);
    }

private:
    __declspec(align(64)) volatile __int64 iValue;
};
```

I cannot use boost.

Edit: 
I'm compiling to x64 but perhaps solutions for 32-bit code would be of help to others.

I don't have access to C++11.

Comment: *`// TODO: Is this correct?`* I think it's correct on 64-bit systems, but not 32-bit systems.

Comment: Have you tried [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) sources? It replaced most (all?) of Sun proprietary code with open-source components, maybe you can take a peak in their implementation of AtomicLong and it's native libraries.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 contains an atomic library, and it is easy if you can use it:

```
class AtomicLong
{
public:
    inline void LazySet(int64_t aValue)
    {
        iValue.store(aValue, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    inline void Set(int64_t aValue)
    {
        iValue.store(aValue);
    }
private:
    std::atomic<int64_t> iValue;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, however VC++ 2010 does not support C++11. What code does the `iValue.store` in LazySet generate?